# How to Format the Labels in a Pie Chart in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In my SSRS 2008 R2 Pie Chart I want to display 3 values which are calculated fields in my dataset.

The dataset collects a bunch of stats for call center agents. Among them are ProductiveTime, ExcepctionTime, NonProductiveTime, for, of course, a given time period.

*If you think you need a bit more details read this paragraph:
The systems keeps track of each change of status in an agent. For example, on break, lunch, in a meeting, training, etc. Then in my stored procedure I create an additional column that has the category of that status, so, for example, lunch, on break will be NonProductiveTime, and so on. Between the selected time period there will be hundreds of entries logging each time there is a change in status, and how long the status lasts.*

So back to the Pie, I am adding the `SUM` of those 3 values to the Chart Data, each one being a series.

The problem I am having, is that when I select the **Series Label Properties** and configure the format for the **Number**, only the first series picks it up. It doesn't make a difference if I do it using the UI or the properties window.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It might be a good idea to mark @lisamai's answer correct since it worked for you (and me, as it turns out)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i had this same issue, if you just use the arrows (little blue arrows at the top of the chart data box) to move the value to the top of the list you can edit the label details/code/expression etc for that series. then just repeat this for all the values you've added.

i'm sure there's a better way but this worked so that's what i did.
It seems that when you are editing a label it is only ever editing the item/value at the top of the list, after you've done your labels then just shuffle them back into the order you wanted them listed

Comment: This absolutely worked for me, and it saved me hours of head-banging. Shame on Microsoft for making it so crazymaking to figure this out. I never would have guessed that shuffling the series location in the list would enable me to adjust the properties of the series' number format.

Answer (score 4):

I have found you can get this with formatting the 'Label' property of the collection 'Chart Series Labels'.  I have also ran into issues with problems of getting enough info of how to format.  I think you can get what you want by some built in 'system syntaxes' used.

Here is an example I used to format the YValue and give me a percent on it's value as well:

#VALY{###,##0} (#PERCENT{p0})

Please see a more inclusive list on this msdn page: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677551.aspx

Comment: This would give me the format for one of the series, but there was no way to get the other "serieses".

Answer (score 1):

You can format your series labels by going to property of each labels, First Right click on all series properties and tick "show data labels" and then select first property and press F4a   property window will open ->under LABELS--> find fonts you can set here.
You can set other properties also here.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure this one out so I went ahead and created a new stored procedure that gives me the data as rows with two columns: one column for the property and one column for the value.
That way I can use just one series for the chart, and to display as percentage, I found this one to be very useful: http://bipassion.wordpress.com/tag/ssrs-pie-chart/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the answers above and my latest VS 2015 
I used these steps

1- Clicked on the Value in **"Chart Data"** box

2- Clicked on **"Show Data Labels"**

3- Press **F4** to open the **"Properties" window** on the side

4- Expand **"Label" section** in the "Properties" window

5- Change **"Label"** and **"Format"** property under Label section in the **"Properties" window**

6- I got a message box says if I want to change the label property then I have to set **"UseValueASLabel"** to **False**